# How do I change the colour of a button when pressed and when pressed the second time to get back to the default colour?

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, vb.net-2010

So I made a script for a pool/snooker business and i have a page with the buttons which represents the tables. The buttons are as default green and when I press on them I want the to turn red and when pressed again to return to the default colour. If you can help me i will be grateful. Thank you very much!

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, WPF?...something else?

Comment: The control really shouldn't store state. You *should* have objects behind the controls which store state. Imagine if you want to add a date/time property to signal when the table becomes available, or something else along those lines... But simply the code in Button1.Click handler could be `Button1.BackColor = If(Button1.BackColor = Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Red)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If WinForms then, assuming you have set button background to Green by default then:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
    If MyButton.BackColor = Color.Green Then
        MyButton.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        MyButton.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

If not using WinForms I suspect a similar approach would work - i.e. check colour first then toggle colour based on result of that check.

Comment: @AmateeseiRoberto ~ Don't forget to accept Jon's answer if he helped you. SO lives and dies by its Q&A system.